# C++: How can I push to elements of an array into a list of arrays?

Tags: c++, list

I get two variables `a` and `b` and want to add them directly to a list of arrays. How can I avoid to define another array, which will be pushed into the list afterwards?

I am searching for a construction similar to the line beginning with `//`.

Minimal example:

```
#include <list>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << endl;

    /* given values */
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    /* arrayList contains arrays of integers. */
    list<boost::array<int, 2> > arrayList;

    /* item to add values */
    boost::array<int, 2> item;

    item[0] = a;
    item[1] = b;
    arrayList.push_back(item);

//  arrayList.push_back({{a, b}});

    cout << arrayList.front()[0] << ", " << arrayList.front()[1] << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

My g++ version is the following:
`gcc-Version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)`.

Compiling (within Eclipse) throws this warning listed as an error:
`Warnung: erweiterte Initialisierungsliste nur mit -std=c++0x oder -std=gnu++0x verfügbar [standardmäßig aktiviert] main.cpp    /testArrayListAndFind   line 24 C/C++ Problem`
which means: `Extended initilization list only with ... or ... available.`

Comment: The answers can vary depending on what compiler you are using. Please specify the compiler (also, C++11 has `std::array`).

Comment: If your code sample is the real code, consider switching to `std::pair` or `std::tuple`.

Comment: Given a C++11 compiler the highlighted line will work exactly as-is: `arrayList.push_back({{a, b}});` Presumably you're asking because that's what you were using on a C++11 compiler and now you have to work on an older compiler. You should specify if that's the case.

Comment: You are correct. Depending on the compiler, the error changes. Thank you, for clarifying this. Thus I added some details to my question.

I found out, that a typecast also is a solution:
`arrayList.push_back((boost::array<int, 2>) {{a, b}});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `boost::assign::list_of` if you don't have C++11 support:

```
arrayList.push_back(boost::assign::list_of(1)(2));
```

Comment: I like this solution because it seems to stay in the boost-concept, even if it is long.

I will use it depending on the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The array that is pushed to the `list` will have to be created, the question is what do you consider acceptable work/typing on your part.

For example, you could create a helper function:

```
boost::array<int, 2> make_array(int a, int b)
{
  boost::array<int, 2> item;
  item[0] = a;
  item[1] = b;
  return item;
}
```

then you can do

```
arrayList.push_back(make_array(a, b));
```

This assumes you will only need 2 elements in the array.  If this is the case, you could just as well use `std::pair<int, int>` instead of `boost::array<>`.  Otherwise, you could create a few overloads of `make_array()`

Comment: Isn't `boost::array` a POD like `std::array`?  Can't you just do `boost::array<int,2> item={{a, b}}; arrayList.push_back(item);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the list to the size you want and mutate the array directly in the list, e.g.,

```
arrayList.resize(10);

for(list::iterator iter = arrayList.begin(); iter != arrayList.end(); ++iter) {
  (*iter)[0] = <value_a>;
  (*iter)[1] = <value_b>;
}
```

Note that *resize()* actually call the constructor of *boost::array* in your example, so the performance saving would be minimal.